# Show a popup when hovering over a link or button in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Is there a method or a way in PowerPoint that will show a popup when I move my mouse cursor over a hyper link or a button and disappears when the mouse moves away form the item?

I'm using Microsoft PowerPoint 2010

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? You should look at http://norvig.com/Gettysburg/

Comment: good question, but 2010, ummmmm....i haven't used it yet

Answer (score 2):

Steps to add a Pop-Up Box in PowerPoint 2010:

1. Insert Shape (for Pop-Up Box)
2. Add Text to Shape
3. Create Animation to Shape - Entrance
4. Select Trigger - Choose the object that you want your pop-up box to appear when clicked
5. Select Animation Pane
6. Create Animation to Shape - Exit
7. Make sure exit animation appears underneath entrance animation

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the desired object on the slide.

   [image]
2. Go to **Insert** tab → **Links** group → **Hyperlink**.
3. In the "Insert Hyperlink" window, click the "ScreenTip" button.

   [image]
4. Type the text that you want into the "ScreenTip text" field.

   [image]
5. Click the "OK" button on the "Set Hyperlink Screen Tip" and "Insert Hyperlink" windows.
6. Test the ScreenTip text by switching to slide show view (<kbd>F5</kbd>) and hovering your mouse over the object with the hyperlink. The screen tip should appear.

[image]

Note: This screenshot was taken in SlideShow view.